# Tried to install a patch on my EE 1.14.2 store and I got a weird error

Tags: patches

```
exxxitt@p3plcpnl0539 [~/public_html]$ sh SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch 
diff: unrecognized option '--git'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 2: index: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 3: ---: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 4: +++: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 5: @@: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 6: usps_Express Mail Hold For Pickup,: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 7: usps_Express Mail International,: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 8: usps_First-Class Mail International Package,: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 9: -: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 10: +: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 11: +: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 12: usps_First-Class Mail International Large Envelope,: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 13: usps_First-Class Mail International,: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 14: usps_Global Express Guaranteed (GXG),: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 15: usps_USPS GXG Envelopes,: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 16: usps_Global Express Guaranteed Non-Document Non-Rectangular,: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 17: usps_Media Mail,: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 18: -: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 19: +: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 20: +: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 21: usps_Express Mail,: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 22: usps_Priority Mail: command not found
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
SUPEE-935_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2013-01-23-05-20-54.patch: line 23: `         ))) {'
```

I've tried to install git because i believe that's why i can't just run the patch like i usually would.

SH and then whatever patch goes here:

Also, i don't have root access because this is a shared server. So it will be tough to install other package variations.

What should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not run the patch script on the server, even if it's not a production environment.

Instead, run it on a local dev environment, commit the resulting changes to your version control system and only then deploy it to the server (whatever your process is to do so)

Comment: So, like whatever files the patch updates or if it writes and creates new files. Check the status of those files and then just push them like i would normally in git with any new additions? Never thought of it that way. Very logical and secure. =]